# Full Screen is exiting when i click internal Link

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my web page i am having one button (fullscreen) when i click on that button it is going for full screen and when i click reset button it is reseting. My requirement is like when i am in full screen mode if i click some other **link** that link should open in full screen mode. my code for your view. please give your suggestion regarding this

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on('click', '#fullscreen', function () {
        var element = document.documentElement;
        if (element.requestFullscreen) {
            element.requestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
        else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
            element.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height);` which should open the new window in full screen.

Comment: By pressing F11 it will go for full screen right. Likewise i am pressing full screen button to go for full screen. if i click any link not going to full screen. I dont have problem in window size and all. it is not going for full screen mode how to acheive it